# Remote Connectivity to Android Device via Appium

Tags: android, networking, appium

Can I connect to an Android Device on a different network with an Appium server that is not on the same network?

Comment: No!! device and appium server should be in same network!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/), its easy to use and the tool comes with the setup of appium done internally. You can just download the application, connect to a physical device or access their cloud devices and start the test development.
You can find their documentation [here](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/EX/Welcome+to+Experitest%27s+Knowledge+Base).